# How do I change nested value in JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to change a specific nested value ("pH") if the "ID" matches , but it only changes the first one and not the one I intended.

What I am trying to do:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "test",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3059"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ID": 1,
                "pH": 3.5,
                "P": 2.8,
                "K": 11.0,
                "Mg": 15.8
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [

                    ]
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ID": 2,
                "pH": 3,
                "P": 2.5,
                "K": 11.1,
                "Mg": 15.8
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [

                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But it changes the "pH value where "ID" is 1 and "pH" value where "ID": 2 stays the same.

Here is my code:

```
import json

with open('filepath', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for feature in data['features']:

        print(feature['properties'])
        if feature['properties']["ID"] == 2:

            data['features'][0]['properties']["pH"]=10
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
            f.truncate()
```

Comment: do not indent when you dump to a file :)

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: remove the `indent=4` from `json.dump(data, f, indent=4)`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know how to change specific value?

Comment: `indent=4` is something you would use in a `print(json.dumps(somethin, indent=4)` for estetics. :)

Comment: I am looking at is as we speak :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to enumerate while you iterate through `data['features']` so you can assign back to the correct value

  - `data['features'][0]` assigns only to `ph` in list index 0.

```py
with open('filepath', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for i, feature in enumerate(data['features']):  # enumerate while iterating

        print(feature['properties'])
        if feature['properties']["ID"] == 2:

            data['features'][i]['properties']["pH"]=10  # assign back to the correct index location
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, f)
            f.truncate()
```

Comment: Hi I have seen some of your answers on stackoverflow. You are amazing ! :)  Can you tell me why you would use f.truncate() in the end of this?

Comment: Ok. I have never used it myself, and I was trying to read about it, but is seem to me that you can only use truncate to limit the file size of the file to some specific value or to get the size of the file printed to the console.

Comment: @mama Without `f.truncate`, the sections of the json are updated in the code, but the uncorrected version of the section is added back into the file at the bottom. So `f.truncate` is required as the code is written. Also, _You are amazing !_ Thank you.

Comment: @mama you can put the sample JSON into a file and run the code to see what happens.

Comment: Yes I am doing it now

Comment: @mama This code writes back to the file, each time it finds `ID=2`. Personally, I would load the file, fix `data` and then write `data` back to a file.

Comment: Ok I see, it removes all the unnecessary spacing, which is provided in the beginning, and avoids the file to get messed up. :) But if the file originally was created by `json.dump()` then it would not be necessary to truncate the file, because the formatting would be correct already. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
data['features'][0]
```

is indexing by [0] and therefore modifying the first "feature" in `data["features"]`. You want it to modify based on the index that evaluates to `True` on your condition `feature['properties']["ID"] == 2`.

Try

```
for index, feature in enumerate(data['features']):
    ...
    if feature['properties']["ID"] == 2:
        data['features'][index]['properties']["pH"] = 10
    ...
```

Comment: how is this different than my answer?